# Add single quotes to value of Input using jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input like this:

```
<input id="myinput">
```

Users are asked to input comma separated values like this: `34323,231213,1212`

How can I convert a string like this into this format using jQuery or javascript:

`'34323','231213','1212'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var val = $('#myinput').val(); // 34323,231213,1212
var converted = val.split(',').map(function(i){return "'"+i+"'";}).join(); // '34323','231213','1212'
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed. I'll accept as soon as I am permitted.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
var inputValue = $('#myinput').val();
var newInputValue = inputValue.replace(/(\d+)/g,'\'$1\'');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way you can use,

```
var inp=$('#myinput').val();
arr=inp.split(',');
newarr=[];
$.each(arr, function() {
  newarr.push("'"+this+"'");
});
console.log(newarr.toString());
```